# How to pass parameters to an already running process of an application

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I am using a utility called Wireless Network Watcher https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_network_watcher.html on a -windows 10 machine- that captures the devices connected to my network and export these items to a csv file periodiacally.

The app also offers some command-line options to start the app in the background and  scan the network and export the items to a file.

But when I get disconnected from my network (and that happens a lot), the scanning process of the app stops and I need to correct this on each disconnect.

I chose to do this by creating a scheduled task that kills the app when disconnection happens and another one to restart it when I get connected again.

But when I do this, I lose the already recorded items on the already running instance of the app (Like devices that were connected and now are not), so I want to use the command-line option to export the items to a file before killing the app.
`C:\WNetWatcher.exe /scomma C:\log.csv`

So my question is: Is it doable to pass some parameters (`/scomma` in my example) to an already running instance of an application, and not starting a new one?

Here are the command Line Options available within the app:

[image: CLI options for WNetWatcher.exe]

Comment: Using the command line invariably creates a _new_ process, and unless an application is explicitly designed to go looking for an existing instance (process) of itself and communicate with it, that new process will have no (intentional) effect on preexisting instances.

Comment: I am sure I can find a way, but you need to show how you currently capture the devices and how you redirect them to a csv file.

Comment: I am currently using the GUI options. There's an option to do a background scan each `x` minutes, it captures all the devices connected. And another option to export to a file when there is a change since the last export each `y` minutes. But I don't need to use them in the specific case I'm talking about (Network disconnection), Just need to do an export (semi-manual one) before killing the process. In the GUI, this export can be done from the context menu, and choosing to save to a file, or by pressing Ctrl+S on the keyboard. I'm not sure if I answered your question

Comment: Well, not really, I need to understand the command line options available for the app, how do you currently run the app, you say you run it from scheduler, so is it done with just the executable, or do you provide switches as well? If you do provide switches, then the command should have a help option and it should help us, help you. try `whatevercommand.exe /?`

Comment: @GerhardBarnard From the scheduler I can run this script: `<EXE Folder>\WNetWatcher.exe /scomma <File Name>. Unfortunately there's no help option with neither of `command help` nor `command /?`. The switches or parameters available to use with the executable are in the link provided in the question, and I'll add a screeshot of all the available ones.

Comment: so what I am seeing is that you basically save the data to a comma delimted file, so it already does save to a file?

Comment: Yes, it does, but when I use that command a new instance of the app runs, and it scans for new  connected devices. What I want is to pass the parameter `/scomma` to the already running instance, so that the generated file would have the previously connected devices for the last `y` interval

Comment: ok, but the app obviously does not cater for that, so why not instead write a batch file that checks the existance of `log.csv` if it already exists, create `log1.csv` etc.? at a later stage you can then just merge the files together.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard My question is if it is possible somehow to pass it to the running process. There'd be no need for that, the app generates files names with the current date and time in it. And I can write that batch to do what you suggest, but that's not my problem.

Comment: Nope, as I said, the app obviously does not cater for that, it is not possible for batch to interact with the process like this.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard I OK, hoped there'd be some way. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Switches/Parameters are processed by the application at the very start. There is no way to give them later. But you mentioned `by pressing Ctrl+S on the keyboard.` - that's possible (but not with pure batch).

Comment: @Stephan That would be great! Would you care to elaborate, please.! There isn't a specific way that I want my goal to be achieved, anything that gets the job done is much appreciated. Also, this method must be able to pick the opened app window and activate it before pressing Ctrl+S

Comment: I don't speak any of the languages that can do this, but if I ever need that, I'd use the [search box](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcmd%5D+sendkey)